# Is it better to declare an empty object using {} or using new Set() when checking for unique values?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I need to validate a sudoku board and I do so by creating a new hash map. Which is the proper way to declare a new "hash map/map"?

```
let row = {};

if (!row[i]) {
  row[i] = 1;
} else {
  return false;
}

VERSUS

let row = new Set();

if (row.has(rows[i])) {
  return false;
} else {
  row.add(rows[i]);
}
```

Side question, would it be better to use const to declare the empty object/new set since I won't be reassigning it but only "adding" values inside?

What I've read so far:
MDN Set
GeeksforGeeks Set

I still don't understand which one is more efficient/better to use in terms of empty obj vs new Set.

Comment: Please define vague terms "better", "proper" etc. From efficiency point of view? Code readability and maintainability point of view? Browser support point of view? ... ? Also pleas do not mix two separate questions into one post

Comment: btw, after `return` in an `if`, you need no `else`.

Comment: For a row in a sudoku-game: why not use an array? `const row = Array(9).fill(null);`

Answer (score 0):

#### `object` vs. `Set`

To use `object` or `Set` **depends on actual code and needs**. It is not really clear from the sample code.

You declare you need a hash**map**. If you really need **map**, i.e. key-value mapping, than **do not** use `Set` (as it does not provide the mapping). Use `object` or `Map` or similar (depending on actual context).

If you merely need to check uniqueness (which the provided code suggests), then do use `Set` (because you do not need hashmap :-)

In the provided code, I would use `Set`.

#### `const`

Concerning `const`, it is similarly simple. Use `const` whenever declaring constants that should not be redeclared. If you are going to redeclare it, do not use `const`...

In the provided code, I would use `const`

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you!!